# Converting multiple integral into iterated integral.

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal A,\mu)$ and $(Y,\mathcal B,\nu)$ are $\sigma$-finite measure space. And $X\times Y$ is product space.And let $f:X\times Y\to [-\infty,\infty]$ be $\mathcal A\times \mathcal B$ measurable and $\mu\times \nu$ integrable function. $~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(1)$

For each $x\in X$ define $f_x:Y\to [-\infty,\infty]$ By $y\mapsto f(x,y)$ .and simillary For each $y\in Y$ define $f_y:X\to [-\infty,\infty]$ By $x\mapsto f(x,y)$.

> **Theorem:1** Assuming $(1)$ then ;
>
> (a) For  $\mu$-almost every $x$ in $X$ ,$f_x$ is $\nu$-integrable and For  $\nu$-almost every $y$ in $Y$ ,$f_y$ is $\mu$-integrable.
>
> (b) The functions $I_f$ and $J_f$ defined By $$I_f(x):=\begin{cases} \int_Y f_x ~d\nu &\text{, if $f_x$ is $\nu$ integrable }  \\ 0&\text{, otherwise }  .\end{cases}$$  $$J_f(y):=\begin{cases} \int_X f_y ~d\mu &\text{, if $f_y$ is $\mu$ integrable }  \\ 0&\text{, otherwise }  .\end{cases}$$
>
> are $\mu$ and $\nu$ integrable respectively.
>
> (c) the relation$$ \int_{X\times Y} f~d(\mu\times \nu)=\int_X I_f~ d\mu=\int_Y J_f~d\nu$$
> holds.

Now let $D=\left\{(x,y) : a\leq x\leq b , m(x)\leq y\leq n(x)\right\}$.where m and n are real valued bounded function on [a,b].and $f:D\subset \Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R$ is continuous function.Here i denote $\lambda$ to be Lebesgue measure on Borel field of $\Bbb R$ and $\lambda\times \lambda$ is Lebesgue measure on Borel field of $\Bbb R^2$ .Now in text We have $$\int_D f~d(\lambda\times \lambda) =\int_{[a,b]} \int_{m(x)}^{n(x)} f~d\lambda \cdot d\lambda \tag{2}$$

Here L.H.S in $(2)$ has certain meaning in Lebesgue sence.So here i will start with L.H.S and prove it is equal to R.H.S .

**Proof:**

Since $D$ is bounded region so $\exists ~$ box $\left[p,q\right]\times [r,s]\subset\Bbb R^2$ such that $D\subset [p,q]\times [r,s]$.Then we have
\begin{align}
\int_D f~d(\lambda\times \lambda)&=\int_{[p,q]\times [r,s]} f\cdot \chi_D \cdot ~d(\lambda\times \lambda)\\~\\
&=\int_{[p,q]} \int_{[r,s]} f\cdot \chi_D \cdot d\lambda ~~d\lambda \tag{Theorem:1}\\~~\\
&=\int_{[p,q]} \int_{[m(x),n(x)]\cup [m(x),n(x)]^c} f\cdot \chi_D \cdot d\lambda ~~d\lambda\\~~\\
&=\int_{[p,q]} \left\{ \int_{[m(x),n(x)]} f\cdot \chi_D \cdot ~d\lambda)+\int_{[m(x),n(x)]^c} f\cdot \chi_D \cdot d\lambda \right\} ~d\lambda\\~~\\
&=\int_{[p,q]} \left\{ \int_{[m(x),n(x)]} f \cdot ~d\lambda)+\int_{[m(x),n(x)]^c} 0 \cdot d\lambda \right\} ~d\lambda\\~~\\
&=\int_{[p,q]} \left\{\int_{[m(x),n(x)]} f\cdot d\lambda \right\} d\lambda \tag{3}\\
\end{align}

**Questions**

(0) Is my proof correct?

(1) In Book they take $m$ and $n$ to be continuous function.where we use continuity of $m$ and $n$?

(2) I think they took continuous  $m$ and $n$ to make sure that function $x\mapsto \int_{[m(x),n(x)]} f\cdot d\lambda$ becomes continuous and we can use FTC ,for second iterated integral .is it correct?

(3) Now from step $(3)$ How to convert $\int_{[m(x),n(x)]} f\cdot d\lambda~$ into **Reimann integral** $~ \int_{m(x)}^{n(x)} f\cdot dx $